# Enclose Code in Latex with single user-defined command

Tags: formatting, mdframed, code

I am using the following to enclose my code in a box and I like the formatting but I have the problem that everytime I have to write a lot of stuff.

Before the `begin{document}` I have defined:

```
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{MyFrame}{%
linecolor=blue,
outerlinewidth=2pt,
roundcorner=10pt,
innertopmargin=2pt,
innerbottommargin=2pt,
innerrightmargin=10pt,
innerleftmargin=10pt,
backgroundcolor=gray!50!white}
```

And everytime I want my box formatted in the right way I have to use:

```
\begin{mdframed}[style=MyFrame]
\begin{verbatim}
# define str(x) #x
cout << str(test);
\end{verbatim}
\end{mdframed}
```

While I would like to have

```
\begin{myAmazingCodeBox}
# define str(x) #x
cout << str(test);
\end{myAmazingCodeBox}
```

Someone could help me?

The box I create is the following by the way (If someone is interested)
[image]

Comment: Have a look at `tcolorbox`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `mdframed` solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{MyFrame}{%
  linecolor=blue,
  outerlinewidth=2pt,
  roundcorner=10pt,
  innertopmargin=2pt,
  innerbottommargin=2pt,
  innerrightmargin=10pt,
  innerleftmargin=10pt,
  backgroundcolor=gray!50!white
}

\newenvironment{myAmazingCodeBox}
  {\verbatim}
  {\endverbatim}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=MyFrame]{myAmazingCodeBox}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[style=MyFrame]
\begin{verbatim}
# define str(x) #x
cout << str(test);
\end{verbatim}
\end{mdframed}

\begin{myAmazingCodeBox}
# define str(x) #x
cout << str(test);
\end{myAmazingCodeBox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is what I was searching for actually. Thanks a lot for your time.

By the way, I want to understand what I am doing, I would like to understand the \surroundwithmdframed instruction. How does it work?

Comment: @minidiable It's explained in the `mdframed` manual

Comment: I have the file which is compiling no problem in Linux (ubuntu 14.04). But when I go to Windows, and texmaker (I use texmaker also in ubuntu) it doesn't work and it gives me the error:

! Undefined control sequence.
l.163 \surroundwithmdframed

Comment: @minidiable Update the TeX distribution.

Comment: I did and now I have an error concerning a QtGui4.dll missing. :(

Comment: @minidiable Sorry, can't help with Windows.

Answer (score 5):

As egreg says, you should give a try to `tcolorbox`. Here is a sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}%

\newtcblisting{myAmazingCodeBox}[1][]{%
colback=gray!50!white,boxsep=2pt,left=2pt,right=2pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,
colframe=blue,arc=10pt,#1}

%\tcbset{listing engine={listings}}
\begin{document}

\begin{myAmazingCodeBox}[listing only]
# define str(x) #x
cout << str(test);
\end{myAmazingCodeBox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Advantage here is that `tcolorbox` seemlessly incorporates `listings` so that you can pass `lstset` options. This means for  `C` code you can have syntax highlighting (from `listings`). All these options are left as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply but I think I am missing something because the result is the following:

http://i1062.photobucket.com/albums/t495/minidiable/Screenshotfrom2014-11-21154319_zpsc389b372.png

Comment: @minidiable You have to add `listing only` as the option (as I did).

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own environment, if you use the `verbatim` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{MyFrame}{%
linecolor=blue,
outerlinewidth=2pt,
roundcorner=10pt,
innertopmargin=2pt,
innerbottommargin=2pt,
innerrightmargin=10pt,
innerleftmargin=10pt,
backgroundcolor=gray!50!white}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\newenvironment{myAmazingCodeBox}%
  {\mdframed[style=MyFrame]\verbatim}%
  {\endverbatim\endmdframed}

\begin{document}
\begin{myAmazingCodeBox}
# define str(x) #x
cout << str(test);
\end{myAmazingCodeBox}
\end{document}
```

But I would prefer the `tcolorbox` solution already posted.